# In what condition we're allowed to omit "that"?

Tags: optional-that

I'm confused whether to put "that" or omit it. Here's the sentence I want to build:

1. Without that

> Until the eighteenth century, charcoal was **the chief fuel** used in
> blast furnaces, as well as in glassmaking, blacksmithing, nd
> metalworking.

2. With that

> Until the eighteenth century, charcoal was **the chief fuel that**
> used in blast furnaces, as well as in glassmaking, blacksmithing, nd
> metalworking.

Which one is correct? Related to the title, hope you will explain a little. Thanks!

Comment: You have omitted the inversion in your question.  It should be "under what conditions _are we_ allowed to omit 'that'?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct. The second is not.

When you add "that" to your second sentence, you're attempting to create a [relative clause](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/relative-clauses.html), but the clause "that used in blast furnaces" doesn't make sense. By simply adding "that" to the sentence, you turn the "chief fuel" into the subject when it should be the object. Then, your subject becomes forced to take an object because *use* is [transitive](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/transitive_verbs.htm) in this context (i.e. requires an object); however, your clause doesn't have one. It's a domino effect of problems, so to speak. As mentioned in another answer, by writing

> Until the eighteenth century, charcoal was the chief fuel that **was** used in blast furnaces, as well as in glassmaking, blacksmithing, *a*nd metalworking.

you're using the passive voice to highlight that the "chief fuel" is the object that others use and not the subject that uses something else.

---

Just to add: if you would like clarification on why the first sentence is correct, it is because the construction is that of my suggested revision of sentence (2), except "that was" is omitted. This is called "reducing" a relative clause, whereby you create a [reduced relative clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107).

Answer (score 1):

The first is *almost* correct, with the verbal phrase "used in blast furnaces" modifying "fuel".

The second *could* be corrected, as below.

Note omission of letter *a* in and in both examples.

Until the eighteenth century, charcoal was the chief fuel that **was** used in blast furnaces, as well as in glassmaking, blacksmithing, [a]nd metalworking.`